# Cocos2d Javascript Schedule task

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-iphone, schedule

How can I change a number in a time interval with Cocos2d Javascript engine?

With pure js I could use `setInterval`, but does any function in the cocos2d library do it?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't write any code so I'll be using the one posted [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32970/how-to-make-a-cross-platform-game-with-cocos2d-javascript-tutorial-getting-started).

To display a number in the center of the screen, that increases every second, I'd add this to MainLayer.js:

```
var MainLayer = cc.LayerColor.extend({
_labelNumber:null,
_number:0,
_updateRate:1.0,

onEnter:function () {
    _number = 0;

    var labelName = ""+_number;
    _labelNumber = cc.LabelTTF.create(labelName, "Arial", 32);
    _labelNumber.setColor(cc.c3(64, 64, 64));
    _labelNumber.setPosition(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);

    _updateRate = 1.0;

    this.addChild(_labelNumber);

    this.schedule(this.updateNumber, _updateRate);
},

updateNumber:function() {
    _number++;

    if(_labelNumber == null) return;

    _labelNumber.setString(""+_number);
}
});
```